# Как сделать мягкие линии в OpenGL?

Tags: c#, opengl, sharpgl

При отрисовке линий у них явно видно как они соскакивают, как рисовать нормально? Чтобы не было острых углов и линии были плавные?

```
    float[] pointers = new float[4] {
        0, 0,
        300, 300
    };


    private void OpenGLControl_OpenGLDraw(object sender, OpenGLEventArgs args) {
        OpenGL gl = args.OpenGL;
        gl.Clear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


        gl.PushMatrix();

        gl.EnableClientState(OpenGL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.VertexPointer(2, 0, pointers);
        gl.DrawArrays(OpenGL.GL_LINES, 0, 2);
        gl.DisableClientState(OpenGL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.End();

        gl.PopMatrix();
    }




    private void OpenGLControl_OpenGLInitialized(object sender, OpenGLEventArgs args) {
        OpenGL gl = args.OpenGL;
        gl.ClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f);
    }



    private void OpenGLControl_Resized(object sender, OpenGLEventArgs args) {
        OpenGL gl = args.OpenGL;

        // Создаем ортографическую проекцию
        gl.MatrixMode(OpenGL.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.LoadIdentity();
        gl.Ortho(0, ActualWidth, ActualHeight, 0, -10, 10);

        // Возвращаемся к модельной проекции
        gl.MatrixMode(OpenGL.GL_MODELVIEW); 
    }
```

P.S. Мой метод (через VertexPointer) нормален для 2D графики? c# потянет такое? Планируется что надо будет отрисовывать десятки тысяч примитивов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит _соскакивают_ ? Ссылка на скриншот была бы кстати.

Comment: Добавил, на скрине видно как линия не гладкая, а лесенкой

Comment: Это сглаживание же обычное. Тысячи ответов на вопрос по запросу `opengl CSAA|MSAA|FXAA`

Comment: Что-то все сводится к тому чтобы понять как это работает и написать самому, везде отдельные куски кода и статьи. OpenGL не является моей целью изучения, будет обидно учить кучу всего ради одной цели и чтоб потом все опять забыть. Неужели нет ничего готового? Или я так плохо ищу?

Comment: Готовое это, наверное, всевозможные движки 2D и 3D. 
При запросе изображений по `glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH)` примеры кода попадаются вместе с примерами получившимися. Попробуйте.